# How to open calendar to todays date if there is no date present in input field using bootstrap datetime picker

Tags: angular, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using Angular8+ and Jquery to open a calendar. I have used bootstrap datetimepicker to open the calendar. Now i have opened calendar and selected a date. And now i delete the date filled in it and open calendar, it opens the calendar with the previously selected month and year of calendar instead of opening to present date.
Kindly help me to solve this.

DEMO:[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qgxox1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

TS:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(".effectiveDate")
      .datetimepicker({ format: "L", useCurrent: false })
      .on("dp.change", e => {
        if (e.date) {
          const date = e.date.format("L");
          this.date = date;

        } else {
          this.date = null;
        }
      });
  }
```

Issue is: Now i choosed 09/09/2009 and i have cleared it, when i again click on Add and click on input it shows me calendar of september 2009, instead of showing current date, month and year.

Comment: Can you plz check with "useCurrent: true" to show  current date selection on opening of calender when click input when it is blank.

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Thanks for response,ya i tried that as well but didnt work

Comment: I have tried not able to reproduce the issue!

Comment: Can you please try now

Comment: @Chellappanவ can you please have a look at this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62831109/how-to-set-time-to-be-1159pm-always-and-disable-the-time-picker-using-jquery-an