# How to set time to be 11:59PM always and disable the time picker using jquery and Angular8

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Hi i have used Angular8+ and Jquery to bind calendar into the input field.But irrespective of time zone, i always want to show time to be 11:59PM and disable the Time Picker and set that to 11:59PM by default.

Can anyone help me how to make this work.

TS:

```
$(".onlyDate").datetimepicker({ format: "L" });
      let dat = null;
       $(".onlyDateTime")
      .datetimepicker()
      .on("dp.hide", e => {
        const date = e.date;
         let dat = e.date.format("L");
        this.Restrictions[this.selectedIndex].datetime = dat.format("MM/DD/YYYY 11:59 A");
      });
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-jb6ipf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-table%2Fuser-table.component.ts)

Comment: It is really not a good idea to mix jQuery with Angular..

Comment: Yes but the requirement made me to choose that way, any help please